# Error in Using Azure Shared Caching Session State Provider

Tags: asp.net, azure, session-state

I am trying to use Azure Shared Caching Session State Provider in My Test Asp.Net Application but receiving following error

> No such host is known Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is
>   known
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SocketException (0x2af9): No such host is known]
>   System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name) +6603642
>   System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean
>   includeIPv6) +106    System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String
>   hostNameOrAddress) +109
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.DnsCache.Resolve(Uri uri) +439

Here is my config

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider" compressionEnabled="false">
      <providers>
        <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider"
             type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
             cacheName="default"
             useBlobMode="true"
             dataCacheClientName="default"/>
      </providers>
    </sessionState>

<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default">
      <hosts>
        <host name="http://dummyPart-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net" cachePort="22233" />
      </hosts>
      <securityProperties mode="Message">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="dummykey"></messageSecurity>
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
    <dataCacheClient name="SslEndpoint">
      <hosts>
        <host name="https://dummyPart-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net" cachePort="22243" />
      </hosts>
      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="dummykey"></messageSecurity>
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
  </dataCacheClients>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it, was using http:// in host name.

```
<host name="https://dummyPart-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net" cachePort="22243" />
```

it should be

```
<host name="dummyPart-cache.accesscontrol.windows.net" cachePort="22243" />
```